# Evaluate $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-(2t+1)^2} e^{-ixt}\,dt$

Tags: calculus

I am trying to evaluate:

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-(2t+1)^2} e^{-ixt}\,dt$$
then
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-(2t+1)^2} [\cos(xt)-i\sin(xt)]\,dt$$
since $\sin(xt)$ is odd, it remains:

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-(2t+1)^2} \cos(xt)\,dt$$

So I couldn't integrate this last integral.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

\begin{align}
& (2t+1)^2 + ixt = 4t^2+4t+1+ixt = 4t^2 + (4+ix)t + 1 \\[10pt]
= {} & 4 \left( t^2 + \left( 1 + \frac{ix} 4 \right)t\right) + 1 \\[10pt]
= {} & 4 \underbrace{\left( t^2 + \left( 1 + \frac{ix} 4 \right)t + \left( \frac 1 2 + \frac{ix} 8 \right)^2 \right)}_\text{This is the complete square.} + 1 - 4\left( \frac 1 2 + \frac{ix} 8 \right)^2 \\[10pt]
= {} & 4 \overbrace{\left( t + \frac 1 2 + \frac{ix} 8 \right)^2}^\text{So is this.}  \underbrace{{} - \frac{ix} 2 + \frac{x^2}{16}}_{ \begin{smallmatrix} \text{The variable $t$ does} \\  \text{not appear in these} \\  \text{three terms.} \end{smallmatrix} } \\[10pt]
= {} & \left( 2t + 1 + \frac{ix} 4 \right)^2 - \frac{ix} 2 + \frac{x^2}{16}.
\end{align}
So the integral is
$$
e^{\left( \displaystyle - \frac{ix} 2 + \frac{x^2}{16} \right)}  \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{\displaystyle-\left( 2t+1+ \frac{ix} 4 \right)^2} \, dt. \tag 0
$$
If you can show this last integral (without the factor that was pulled out in front) is equal to
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-4t^2} \, dt,
$$
then we're almost done.
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-4t^2} \, dt = \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-\frac{t^2}{2\sigma^2}} \, dt \quad\text{where }\sigma = \frac 1 {2\sqrt 2}. \tag 1
$$
The usual form of the normal density tells us that
$$
\frac 1 {\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-\frac{t^2}{2\sigma^2}} \, dt = 1,
$$
so that tells you the value of $(1)$.

But why should
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{\displaystyle-\left( 2t+1+ \frac{ix} 4 \right)^2} \, dt
$$
be equal to
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-4t^2} \, dt \text{ ?}
$$
One could try to do this by substitution: $2u = 2t + 1 + \dfrac{ix} 2 $, $du = dt$, etc.  Then as $t$ goes from $-\infty$ to $+\infty$, then $u$ goes from what to what?  From $-\infty+\text{some imaginary number}$ to $+\infty+\text{the same imaginary number}$.  How to deal with the imaginary part?

Consider
$$
\int_{-M}^M e^{-2t^2} \,dt + \int_M^{M+ ia} \cdots + \int_{M+ia}^{-M+ia} \cdots + \int_{-M+ia}^{-M} \cdots
$$
following straight lines from the lower to the upper bound of integration in each case.  This is an integral of an entire function over a closed path and is therefore $0$.

If we can now show that the two parts
$$
\int_M^{M+ia} e^{-2t^2}\,dt \text{ and } \int_{-M+ia}^{-M} \cdots \tag 2
$$
approach $0$ as $M\to\infty$, then the two integrals from $-\infty$ to $+\infty$ and from $-\infty+ia$ to $+\infty+ia$ must both be the same.

The two limits in $(2)$ are found by getting a bound on the size of the function on those two paths.

Comment: There is missing 4 in third step from beginning in front of expression (1/2 + ix/8)^2 in the end.

Comment: @Melina : It should look alright now. $\qquad$

Comment: ...+1-4(1/2+ix)^2  in stead of ...+4-4(1/2+ix)^2

Comment: I made this as accepted answer but there's still a problem because solution must be: e^{-ix/2 - x^2/16} instead of e^{-ix/2 + x^2/16} but I don't see where's mistake!!! But I like your way!!!
And constant is ok.

Answer (score 5):

$\begin{eqnarray}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-(2t+1)^2}e^{-itx}dt&=&\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-(1+4t+4t^2)}e^{-itx}dt\\
&=&\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-4(t^2+t+\frac{1}{4})}e^{-itx}dt\\
&=&\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-\frac{\left(t+\frac{1}{2}\right)^2}{1/4}}e^{-itx}dt\\
&=&\frac{\sqrt{2\pi}}{\sqrt{8}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\sqrt{8}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{\left(t+\frac{1}{2}\right)^2}{2\frac{1}{8}}}e^{-itx}dt\\
&=&\frac{\sqrt{2\pi}}{\sqrt{8}}M_T(-ix)\tag1
\end{eqnarray}$

where $T$ is a normal with $\mu=-\frac{1}{2}$ and $\sigma^2=\frac{1}{8}$ and $M_T$ is its generating moments function.

Thus, in $(1)$, $M_T(-ix)=e^{\mu (-ix)+\frac{\sigma^2(ix)^2}{2}}=e^{-\frac{ix}{2}-\frac{x^2}{16}}$.

Therefore $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-(2t+1)^2}e^{-itx}dt=\frac{\sqrt{2\pi}}{\sqrt{8}}e^{-\frac{ix}{2}-\frac{x^2}{16}}$$

Comment: Is there any chance to solve without MGF?

Comment: Shouldn't the integral be real for real $x$?

Comment: Definitively the integral is not a real number for $x$ real. On the other hand, there are many ways to solve it. For example using Fourier transform, Cauchy Formula or multiple integration. In no case the integral can be derived from elemental methods, cause it will involves a term looks like $\int e^{-s^2}ds$

Comment: nice.............+1

Comment: @sinbadh I am sorry but it looks that it is not right something: (2t+1)^2 it is not equal to (4t^2-4t+1); you can see from second step.